# Joining multiple lines into single line in ArcGIS Desktop?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, editing, attribute-joins, line

In ArcGIS, I have digitized roadmap in shapefile, and i want to join several lines into one (singlepart) line, NOT merging (i.e., I want to join from one's node to another node). The feature exist in QGIS using "join multiple lines" plugin.

How do I perform the task in ArcGIS Desktop?

Comment: I think you should include a picture of what you are trying to describe.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [Dissolve](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/tools/data-management-toolbox/h-how-dissolve-data-management-works.htm) tool and check `Unsplit line (Optional)` as you can see below:

[image]

Comment: I think this only works when the lines have a vertex in common. The "Join Multiple Lines Plugin" fill the gaps between lines.

Comment: @Ernesto561 In my understanding to his question, he wants to join together the nodes in common. If this is not the case, then he needs to give more details to what he wants to do.

Comment: Dissolve will construct multi-part lines without a plugin.